# Express returning "User is not authorized" when modifying object from another user

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, express, mongoose

I have a Classroom model that looks like this:

```
/**
 * Classroom Schema
 */
var ClassroomSchema = new Schema({
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    participants: [{
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }],
    lesson: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Lesson',
        required: 'Define a lesson for this classroom',
    },
    user: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    currentTaskIndex: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
});
```

As you can see, the model keeps a reference to the user that have created the Classroom (User) and it also has many participants (more Users).

I'm trying to add the functionality to allow other Users (not the creator of the Classroom) to join the Classroom by sending a PUT request to the classroom API with a new User in the participants field. However, since the User sending the request is not the one who created the object, Express is returning a 403 (Forbidden):

```
exports.hasAuthorization = function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.classroom.user.id !== req.user.id) {
        return res.status(403).send('User is not authorized');
    }
    next();
};
```

What's the best approach/pattern to solve this allowing Users to join Classrooms created by another User but not to do other actions like deleting the object. Other fields might be updated by another participants, like the currentTaskIndex.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could add a 'master' or 'admin' field to your classroom, and store the Creator's userId in it.

Then you can allow the delete/modify, etc actions only for the user who is master of this particular classroom, while letting everyone in.